# How to convert ocean shape file into topojson

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have gdal 1.10.1 and topojson 1.4.0 installed on my MacOs 10.7.5.
I have downloaded the [ne_110m_ocean](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/) form Natural Earth.

I successfully transformed the shape file in GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  ocean.json \
  ne_110m_ocean.shp
```

Then I transformed the GeoJSON into topojson:

```
topojson \
  -o ocean_tj.json \
  ocean=ocean.json \
```

When I plot using the GeoJSON file all works fine.

```
d3.json("ocean.json", function(json) {
  svg.selectAll("path")
 .data(json.features)
 .enter()
 .append("path")
 .attr("d", path)
 .style("fill", "steelblue");
});
```

When I plot using the topojson file, instead of having the polygons of the oceans I get the polygons of the lands!!!!

```
d3.json("ocean_tj.json", function(topology) {
var ocean = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.ocean); 
svg.append("path")
.datum(ocean)
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", "red");
});
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also get some strange results when working with that file.  Basically I had a strip down the middle of the data where the ocean and land were reversed.  I used [ShapeEscape](http://www.shpescape.com/mix/).  I'd post something over on Google Groups and see if anyone over there has any ideas.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this happens, but using the `no-force-clockwise` fix the issue. I will investigate a little more and fill a bug report if it's necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the option `--no-force-clockwise` fix the issue:

```
topojson -o ocean_tj.json ocean=ocean.json --no-force-clockwise
```