# How can I remove a line from the 110m TopoJson world map?

Tags: d3.js, maps, topojson

I have created a map using D3 with the [110m world map](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/examples/world-110m.json) and the mercator projection. I rotated the map by -10 degrees to get it lined up how I want then set the stroke and fill. After doing this I noticed that there is a line through the Chukchi Peninsula (the bit that is often found to the left of Alaska).

[image: Chukchi Peninsula]

Reviewing the rendering on GitHub and also [another map made with this projection](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6621971), it seems like this line is actually in the data.

[image: Rendering from GitHub]
[image: Another example]

Is there any way to get rid of it (editing the TopoJSON, re-generating it the shape, or some other means)?

Comment: Hum, this is similar to [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023995/how-to-convert-ocean-shape-file-into-topojson) which I *think* was also using the 110m dataset.  Perhaps that solution will work here?

Comment: AFAIK none of the usual GIS tools support topojson, so you would have to modify whatever it was generated from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, you need to fix your data by hand, say by editing the TopoJSON directly, or by converting the Shapefile to GeoJSON and then doing a similar edit, or by using a Shapefile editor.

In the future, the `topojson` command-line tool should be able to fix this for you by stitching together polygons that cross the [antimeridian (±180° longitude)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian), removing antimeridian cuts that are often present in currently-available geometry.

It’s already the case that `topojson` removes antimeridian cuts. However, currently it can only remove antimeridian cuts within a single ring, and here the Russia polygon has been split into two (or more) rings where it crosses the antimeridian; `topojson` is not yet smart enough to stitch multiples rings cut at the antimeridian back into a single ring. (You might be able to use [topojson.mesh](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416405) to do this, however.)

As for why the antimeridian cuts are there in the first place: many geo tools don’t fully support spherical coordinates, so it’s common to find data that cuts polygons along the antimeridian to prevent [visual artifacts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3788999) from appearing when projecting. (You can read about antimeridian cuts in my [For Example talk](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/example/).) D3 and `topojson` use true spherical coordinates with great-arc interpolation between points, so that you can represent polygons that surround poles or cross the antimeridian without cuts. However, because most existing data is precut at the antimeridian, `topojson` must remove the cuts to restore the true spherical geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your [state example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416440) gave me an idea that worked: I simply drew another copy of the land with a fill but no stroke on top of the first one. This covers up the lines over -180º and should work for my purposes.